# C program crashes after printing few lines

Tags: c

I have written this piece of code in C, but when I run it, the program crashes after printing few lines. Please solve the problem.

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


void main() {

    char *str[] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Hen", "Goat"};
    char *sentence;
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        sentence = strdup("");
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        printf("%s\n", sentence);
    }

}
```

Comment: The first argument of `strcat` point to a buffer with enough space allocated for the result.

Comment: I have ran it, and it doesn't crash by me. Why it crashes by you is because you invoked undefined behavior when you didn't allocate your pointer properly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program crashed because `sentence` didn't have enough memory allocated to store the string.

```
void main() {

    char *str[] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Hen", "Goat"};
    char *sentence = NULL; //initialize the string
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        sentence=malloc(13); // longest string would be GoatGoatGoat + terminating null
        sentence[0]='\0';
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand()%4]);
        printf("%s\n", sentence);
        free(sentence); //always free the allocated memory
    }


}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior since `malloc()`ed pointer points to array with *indeterminate* contents. `strcat()` requires a null-terminated string as argument.

Comment: Use `calloc` instead... Or set the first character to `0` explicitly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or just `strcpy()` instead of the first `strcat()`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is it now better?

Comment: Yes, now the behavior is defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = strdup("");
```

You're only allocating 1 `char` for `sentence`. You need to allocate enough memory to store all 3 animal names (13 = 3 times the longest animal name, goat + 1 null character). Also, use `calloc` to zero out the string.

```
sentence = calloc(13, sizeof(char));  /* CORRECT */
```

Also, you're not freeing your memory when you are done:

```
free(sentence);
```

By the way, you should not use `void main()` as it is not standards compliant. Use `int main()` instead.

Comment: Actually he needs to allocate enough space to store 4 times the *maximum* name length, as it is picking the random one each time.

Comment: @chux fixed to use `calloc`

Comment: Consider the signature `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` uses 2 arguments.  suggest `sentence = calloc(13, sizeof *sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's a bad idea to allocate and free memory in the loop. It's harmless, but it's much better to reuse allocated memory in this case.

You also don't have to use malloc and free, and can instead declare a char array of a fixed length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[] = {"Dog", "Cat", "Hen", "Goat"};
    char sentence[64];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        strcpy(sentence, str[rand() % 4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand() % 4]);
        strcat(sentence, str[rand() % 4]);
        printf("%s\n", sentence);
    }
    return 0;
}
```